# Collect all IPs (v4,v6) using regex fails

Tags: javascript, regex, ipv6

Variable `source` contains IP addresses that I'm trying to get in array `ips`, but something goes wrong and I cannot find the mistake...

`var ips = source.match(/((^\s*((([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\s*$)|(^\s*((([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,2})|:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,3})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,4})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,2}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,5})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,3}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,6})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,4}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(:(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,7})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,5}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:)))(%.+)?\s*$))\b/g);`

Comment: Variable `source` is a string containing IP addresses, correct?

Comment: Yes, Acidic, correct!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by, "_something goes wrong_." I plugged this into my RegEx tool, and you have some things that I would consider problems. For example, you are requiring some type of whitespace after the beginning of the string, but before the IP address. The resulting report is far too large for this site, but without knowing exactly what your source looks like and what you are really trying to get from it, there are a lot of things I would consider problems.

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided a verifiable sample I will provide an working end-to-end [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ahlWm8/1) based on Syzdek's excellent [ipv6-regex-test.sh](https://gist.github.com/syzdek/6086792).

The regex expression:

`(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|
[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|
:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|
fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|
::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}
((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}
(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:
((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}
(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))
|((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])`

Demo code:

```js
var ips = new Array();;
const regex = /(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))|((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])/g;
const str = `3ffe:1900:4545:3:200:f8ff:fe21:67cf
fe80:0:0:0:200:f8ff:fe21:67cf
192.168.0.1`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    // capturing group 0: full match
    console.log(m[0]);
    ips.push(m[0]);
}

console.log(ips);
```